# Child process events when finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn

There is a way to extend child_process events of nodejs
it seems that some times events are not invoked so I want to see if the process was ended and then fire event.
for example I use spawn and the process was **succeeded** but non of the following events was invoked, so can I track somehow via event or something when the spawn process was finished ?

```
function childProcessPromise(mtd, cmd, options) {
    var child = child_process.spawn(cmd, value, opt);
    child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('data' + data);
    });
    child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('test: ' + data);
        reject(data);
    });
    child.on('close', function (code) {
        console.log("close");
    });
    child.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

  });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doc suggests what you're observing might be correct:

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_close

Event: 'close'#

> code Number the exit code if the child exited on its own. signal
>   String the signal by which the child process was terminated. The
>   'close' event is emitted when the stdio streams of a child process
>   have been closed. This is distinct from the 'exit' event, since
>   multiple processes might share the same stdio streams.

Since by default the child streams are shared with the parent, the streams wont close as long as the parent is open

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

I have little experience with spawn and have not seen this hands on, but that's the way i'm interpreting the docs

Comment: Thanks but there is no way to get some feedback that the process is running ? currenlty the process is running but I dont have any event which inform that,any idea?

Comment: @Mark could you post your child process? is it writing to stdout?

Comment: No I dont got any of those event(include stdout) but the process was succeeded I need somehow to trigger some event that the process was started...any idea how to do it in node?

Comment: could could establish and 'ipc' channel when creating the process, which willl allow the child and the parent to communicate through `process.send()` and `process.on('message')`

Comment: Can you please provide some example as answer how can I put just for instance a console.log inside the process send and process.on('msg;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you assist please?